# Resolving distance constraints in 2D

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, constraint-satisfaction

I am currently writing a tool that will be used in an industrial process to place components with physical requirements. It boils down to the following:

- I have a set of points (typically, a few thousands);
- I need to place these points on a (2D) plane;
- for each pair A, B of points, I have a constraint that is either

  - the distance between A and B must be some distance D±delta; or
  - the distance between A and B must be at least some distance D.

Of course, this problem does not always have a solution.

Now, that sounds like a fairly classical graph embedding. But there's a catch: once the tool works, it will be put in the hands of people with limited understanding of the problem, which means that I need the algorithm to be mostly reproducible (if it succeeded once, it needs to succeed when we run it again and to produce a comparable solution) and failures to be somewhat explainable.

On the upside, I am ok with having a percentage of false negatives (there is a solution but the algorithm can't find it), as long as it doesn't break the constraints above. Also, I don't care about edge intersections.

Any idea? Happy to take bibliographical sources!

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the set of points must satisfy. Are the values $D$ and $\delta$ the same for all constraints in the same instance, or can they differ? I'm also not so sure whether modelling this problem as finding a graph embedding is a good idea, can you explain why you want to interpret the problem in this way?

Comment: As for the additional requirements, do you simply want the algorithm to be non-random, or do you want the algorithm to stable: to give a solution that is similar after small changes in the input. I'm not sure why a failure should be explainable. If you can explain exactly what went wrong, you should be able to fix it, no?

Comment: "I need to place these points on a (2D) plane" - does it mean you can choose their coordinates? If yes, then how freely?